# Need a good method for computing $\int _{\infty }^a\:\frac{1}{\left(x^2-1\right)^p}dx$

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, numerical-methods, algorithms, improper-integrals

I need a good method for computing $$\int _{\infty }^a\:\frac{1}{\left(x^2-1\right)^p}dx$$
Where $p>0$ and $a>1$ are real. Maybe you have a good numerical algorithm for such a computation? That would really help me, thank you.

Comment: The integrand is decreasing very, very fast. If $a>10, p>3$ you can basically say it goes to zero.

Comment: @xpaul Why don't you write $1$ as $-1$?

Comment: @xpaul Does not really matter, I am sorry if this bothers you. But still, both of them are equally hard.

Comment: @vitamind And what if not?

Comment: It doesn't matter. The normal way is to write from $a$ to $\infty$.

Comment: There is a closed form for the integral if $p\in\mathbb{N}$ (maybe also for $p/2,p\in\mathbb{N}$).  So you can approximate it with the floor and ceiling function to get a lower and upper bound. I will write an answer where I will elaborate.

Comment: This question can't be answered without additional information: what is a "good" numerical algorithm, in this case? That would depend on the range of possible values of $a$ and $p$. For $p\le1/2$, the integral isn't even convergent. For large $a$, an asymptotic expansion might give sufficient accuracy... if we knew what means "sufficient accuracy" for you.

Comment: @NoNames I value speed over accuracy. I had a similar problem with the denominator in the numerator and found and excellent answer way which was accurate up to the 6th digit after the decimal point. Still, everything can help me as now I am clueless on ways to solve.

Comment: Are you specifically looking for a numerical recipe? Or is an approximation sufficient? If so, tell us if you're interested in large or small $a$, or large or small $p$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For integer values of $p$, there are very nica patterns for
$$I_p=\int\limits_{a}^{\infty}\frac{dx}{(x^2-1)^p}$$ We have
$$\color{blue}{I_p=(-1)^{p}\,\frac {a\, J_p}{2^{p-1}\, (p-1)!\,(a^2-1)^{p-1}}  +}$$ $$\color{blue}{(-1)^{p+1}\, 4^{1-p}\, \binom{2 p-2}{p-1}\,\coth ^{-1}(a)}$$ where $J_p$ represents a polynomial of degree $(p-2)$ in $a^2$.

The first of these are
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
p & J_p \\
 2 & 1 \\
 3 & 3 a^2-5 \\
 4 & 15 a^4-40 a^2+33 \\
 5 & 105 a^6-385 a^4+511 a^2-279 \\
 6 & 945 a^8-4410 a^6+8064 a^4-7110 a^2+2895 \\
 7 & 10395 a^{10}-58905 a^8+137214 a^6-166914 a^4+110055 a^2-35685
\end{array}
\right)$$ in which more patterns could be found.

For example, the coefficient of the largest power is $(2n-3)!!$ and the constant term is $(-1)^n \big[(2 n-2)!!-(2 n-3)!!\big]$

Comment: Thank you for your helpful answer. Could you please explain briefly how you derived this formula? What was the idea?

Comment: @Algo. Very simple ! Just working hard knowing that there must be several patterns. If you like this answer, may be you could accept it. Cheers :-)

Answer (score 2):

**Some useful information**

1. The integral converges if $a>1$ and $p>1/2$.
2. The integrand is decreasing rapidly. We will only have to look at a few small values.
3. We define the integral
   $$I(a,p)=\int\limits_{a}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(x^2-1)^p}\,\mathrm{d}x.$$

**For big $p$**

> [image]

In this graph we set $p=50$. You can see that the values are very small. The spike at $3$ might seem confusing, but note that that the $y$-values only go up to $2.5\cdot 10^{-40}$. Also observe that if we increase $a$, the integral area under the integrand get's smaller and smaller. I will only work out some values for $p\le3$.

**For $p\le3$**

Here are the values for $p/2$, where $p\in\mathbb{N}$ and $p<6$.

| Input | Output | Logical $a$ |
| --- | --- | --- |
| $I(a,1)$ | $-\dfrac{\ln\left(a+1\right)-\ln\left(a-1\right)}{2}$ | - |
| $I(a,1.5)$ | $1-\dfrac{a}{\sqrt{a^2-1}} $ | $a<50$ |
| $I(a,2)$ | $\dfrac{\left(a^2-1\right)\ln\left(a+1\right)-\ln\left(a-1\right)a^2-2a+\ln\left(a-1\right)}{4a^2-4}$ | $a<10$ |
| $I(a,2.5)$ | $\frac{\sqrt{a^2-1}\left(2a^3-3a\right)}{3a^4-6a^2+3}-\dfrac{2}{3}$ | $a<5$ |
| $I(a,3)$ | $-\dfrac{\left(3a^4-6a^2+3\right)\ln\left(a+1\right)-3\ln\left(a-1\right)a^4-6a^3+6\ln\left(a-1\right)a^2+10a-3\ln\left(a-1\right)}{16a^4-32a^2+16}$ | $a<4$ |

What I mean by "Logical $a$" is a (nice) value, where the output $I(a,p)$ is $>0.0001$, except for $p=1$. So as you can see, for $p=1$ it really makes sense to get a closed form. To get values (from hand) between $p$ and $p+0.5$, you can use the values in the table for upper and lower bounds. If you can use a computer to evaluate these values, I don't see a problem to do this with arbitrary $p$. Also if you are looking for a good calculator, I recommend Mathematica or Matlab.

Comment: It would be nice to find what are "my" polynomials. Any idea ? Cheers and $\to +1$

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! I did not understand what you meant by Here are the values for $p/2$. And how did you derive the table? using some software? Anyways I will now look at Mathematica and Matlab and see if these websites can be useful to me.

Comment: 1. For evaluating the Output the integral was not hard to calculate. For evaluating "Logical $a$" I used a soft ware. 2 I thought you wanted to calculate the integral numerically and my answer is written in a numerical point of view. Apparently not, very good answer @Claude Leibovici. Have a nice day guys!